# Turtle Location Not Working

Tags: python

Heres the following code:

```
while True:
    if turtle.xcor() >= 350 or <= -350:
        print 'yes'
```

it always prints 'yes'

help?

Comment: `or <= -350:` is nonsense, not sure how this even works

Comment: I doubt it can *ever* `print 'yes'`, given that your condition is clearly a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Also see [this duplcate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 3):

change

```
if turtle.xcor() >= 350 or <= -350:  #this has a syntax error
```

to

```
if turtle.xcor() >= 350 or turtle.xcor() <= -350:
```

or

```
if abs(turtle.xcor()) >= 350: # thanks – @vaultah
```

or

```
if not 350 <= turtle.xcor() >= -350: # thanks - @jonrsharpe
```

Comment: or `abs(turtle.xcor()) >= 350`

Comment: See the comment left for you by @rto32, [in the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36824677/3).

Comment: @Mogsdad I corrected it, I don't know why I didn't notice it before I am blind

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not print anything as there is a syntax error.

You could write

```
while True:
    if not (-350 < turtle.xcor() < 350):
        print 'yes'
```

See [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) for this shortcut notation, which is seldom found in other languages. Also while the parentheses are not required in this case (see [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)), I think they add some clarity to the expression.